# UITableView crashing when executing delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The code is below:

```
@interface PreferenceViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UITableView * preference;
    UISegmentedControl * dimension;
    NSArray * timeslot;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView * preference;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * dimension;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * timeslot;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    preference.delegate = self;
    preference.dataSource = self;
    timeslot = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7:00-8:00", @"8:00-9:00", @"9:00-10:00", @"10:00-11:00", @"11:00-12:00", @"12:00-13:00", @"13:00-14:00", @"14:00-15:00", @"15:00-16:00", @"16:00-17:00", nil];
    NSLog(@"size of array is %d", [timeslot count]);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table View delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (dimension.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        return [timeslot count];
    }else
        return 15;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSLog(@"TESTING");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // this is the MAGIC line!

    if (dimension.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        cell.text = [timeslot objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Was wondering what's causing the crash? It happens in that numberOfRowsInSection delegate and the call to timeslot count..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    timeslot = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7:00-8:00", @"8:00-9:00", @"9:00-10:00", @"10:00-11:00", @"11:00-12:00", @"12:00-13:00", @"13:00-14:00", @"14:00-15:00", @"15:00-16:00", @"16:00-17:00", nil];
```

This line should have `-retain`.

```
timeslot = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7:00-8:00", @"8:00-9:00", @"9:00-10:00", @"10:00-11:00", @"11:00-12:00", @"12:00-13:00", @"13:00-14:00", @"14:00-15:00", @"15:00-16:00", @"16:00-17:00", nil] retain];
```

UPD `-autorelease` is not a good idea. You can only autorelease/release objects that you own. When you used `-arrayWithObjects` your object is owned by local AutoreleasePool.

Here is how it works in simple terms. Every time you create an object **without** `-alloc` or `-copy` methods it's autoreleased, which here means it will have reference count 1 until the end of the scope of the message. Techically autorelease pool business is **asynchronous**, so it may crash or may not, but you should assume this object is zombie at this point. So you must use `-retain` in order to preserve this object for another method's use. if you used explicitly `-retain` you must use `-release` explicitly when you are done with this object. So why not to use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]` right away. it's just more appropriate here. You can use retained property here too, but you don't want to expose internal variable when you don't have too.

Comment: That would only make the problem worse. The array returned by `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` is not owned by you, so autoreleasing it would cause it to eventually be released too many times.

Comment: @Anomie I understand the underlying process very well. You don't need to teach me. About "it would cause it to eventually be released too many times" is really funny.

Comment: @Anomie it's the shortest solution which seems appropriate to the coding style above. I wouldn't fix it that way too, I just wouldn't have to.

Comment: I see you corrected your post now, good. But do note that he already has the retained property in the code he posted above, so it's not a matter of *adding* one. You may also want to edit your post to make it more clear that an autoreleased object can be used without issue within your method and can even be returned without issue, the problem is just in storing it for later without retaining.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad`, you are assigning the newly-created (and autoreleased) NSArray to the ivar rather than the property, which means that it is *not* retained for you. Thus, by the time it gets to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` the array has been disposed of and you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS or a similar crash.

For this reason, I usually name my ivars `_name` rather than `name` to match the property. This does mean that the synthesize line must be the more complicated `@synthesize name=_name`, but it prevents accidentally assigning to the ivar rather than the property.

Comment: you're saying I should change @synthesize timeslot to @synthesize timeslot=_timeslot; ? as I tried that too and it didn't work

Comment: @EquinoX don't listen to him. You would need a retained property here. Just change `arrayWithObjects` to `initWithObjects` and release your allocated object once you are done with it.

Comment: @bioffe thanks dude.. but mind explaining with arrayWithObjects doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, using `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]` would also work here. @EquinoX: I'm saying you should use `self.timeslot = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]`, setting it via the property rather than accessing the ivar directly.

Comment: @EquinoX: The second paragraph of my comment is just pointing out that, if you rename the ivar to `_timeslot` and change the `@synthesize` line to match, then you cannot accidentally assign the ivar rather than the property by forgetting the `self.` because the names no longer match. But that's not at all something *necessary* to do.

Comment: @EquinoX Here is how it works in simple terms. Every time you create an object without -alloc or -copy methods it's autoreleased, which here means it will have reference count 1 until the end of the scope of the message. Techically it's asynchronous, so it may crash or may not, but you should assume this object is zombie at this point. So you must use `-retain` in order to preserve this object for another method's use.  if you used explicitly `-retain` you must `-release` explicitly too. So why not to use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]` right away. it's just more appropriate here.